# Using styled components "as" prop with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, styled-components

I'm currently building a pattern library in which I've built a `Button` component using `React` and `styled-components`.
Based on the `Button` component, I want all my `Link`s component to look exactly the same and receive exactly the same props.
For that purpose, I'm using the `as` prop from `styled-components`, which allows me to use that already built element as another tag or component.

**Button Component**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { ButtonBorderAnimation } from './ButtonAnimation'
import { ButtonProps, ButtonVariant } from './Button.types'
import { ButtonBase, LeftIcon, RightIcon } from './Button.styled'

function Button({
  variant = ButtonVariant.Filled,
  children,
  leftIcon = null,
  rightIcon = null,
  ...props
}: ButtonProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <ButtonBase variant={variant} {...props}>
      {variant !== ButtonVariant.Ghost ? (
        <ButtonBorderAnimation {...props} />
      ) : null}
      {leftIcon ? <LeftIcon>{leftIcon}</LeftIcon> : null}
      {children}
      {rightIcon ? <RightIcon>{rightIcon}</RightIcon> : null}
    </ButtonBase>
  )
}

export default Button
```

**Button Types**

```
export interface ButtonProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
  variant?: 'filled' | 'outlined' | 'ghost'
  size?: 'small' | 'regular'
  underlinedOnHover?: boolean
  leftIcon?: React.ReactNode
  rightIcon?: React.ReactNode
  inverse?: boolean
}

export enum ButtonVariant {
  Filled = 'filled',
  Outlined = 'outlined',
  Ghost = 'ghost',
}

export enum ButtonSize {
  Small = 'small',
  Regular = 'regular',
}
```

**Link Component**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Button from '../Button/Button'
import { Link as LinkRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { LinkProps } from './Link.types'

function Link({ to, ...props }: LinkProps): JSX.Element {
  return <Button to={to} as={LinkRouter} {...props} />
}

export default Link
```

**Link Types**

```
import { ButtonProps } from '../Button/Button.types'
import { LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom'

type RouterLinkWithButtonProps = ButtonProps & LinkProps

export interface LinkProps extends RouterLinkWithButtonProps {}
```

When I do the above, this problem comes us...

```
Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps'.
```

...which makes sense because button doesn't have the prop `to` which is required for the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`.

How will you approach something like this? Where when using the `Button` the `to` prop shouldn't even be in the type and when using the `Link` the `to` should be required.

**Uses**

```
<Button>Hello</Button>
<Link to="/somewhere">Hello</Link>
```

Comment: Why not define `button` component to have a `Link` inside? In your file `../Button/Button` ?

Comment: Is it possible to show your `button` implementation? Will be more easy to answer then.

Comment: @its4zahoor Added the button implementation in the question.

Comment: @its4zahoor The answer to you first comment is: I would like to treat them separately, but still having the same style and props. This is more a typescript kind of problem, not a react one.

Comment: This might give some ideas https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c

Comment: This is a work around, check this https://spectrum.chat/styled-components/general/typescript-extending-a-styled-component-and-overriding-the-as-prop~76beee1d-610c-437d-844f-0fd4bcadac36

Comment: You can create a facade on top of your union. See this tweet for intuition: https://twitter.com/WrocTypeScript/status/1122952350178643968

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
function Link(_props: LinkProps): JSX.Element {
  const props = { as: LinkRouter, ..._props };
  return <Button {...props} />
}
```

Note that TypeScript applies [strict object literal assignment checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) which can be loosened by assigning an object literal to a variable beforehand instead of directly passing it as, for example, an function argument, which is consistent with the React component props assignment behavior.

```
declare function foo(arg: { a: number }): void;

foo({ to: '', a: 1 }); // error

const arg = { to: '', a: 1 };
foo(arg); // no error
```